# Transact SQL and Where Statement and CASE Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following requirement that will multiple joins - Currently this search looks at the client’s residence county. This needs to be changed to look at `tbl_client_insurance.region_id` for the active, effective insurance for the consumer.  If the client has multiple insurances meeting this criteria, use the county for ins_id = 2 (Medicaid). I believe I have most of the query correct, but I am getting hung up on the ti.ins_id, which I believe I will need a case, basically returning only the 2 or else if 2 does not exist return the insurance the client does have.

```
SELECT 
    ti.client_id, ti.exp_dt, ins_id, * 
FROM 
    tbl_Client AS tc
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_client_insurance AS ti ON ti.client_ID = tc.client_ID
WHERE 
    tc.client_id = 26 
    AND tc.active = 1
    AND (ti.exp_dt >= GETDATE() OR ti.exp_dt IS NULL)
    CASE
    --- Need some help here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to add such a condition to your join logic as

```
INNER JOIN tbl_client_insurance AS ti ON ti.client_ID = tc.client_ID AND ti.ins_id=2
```

Comment: This is true, however, if that insurance does not exist I will need to return the other insurance if any.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your desired result set is.
Based on your sample you want all matching client insurances.
But it seems you may want just one for that client.

If you just want one for that client, this is just an ordering issue.
You should use a UNION ALL.
The first part is the query for insurance id 2.
The second part is the query for all other insurances.
Order by a new column you provide.
For the first part the new column will be A.
For the second part it will be B.
Then take only the top 1 row.

That way if id 2 exists it will be first, otherwise it will be one of the other insurances, or if there are no matching insurances you will get an empty result set.

The question then becomes how do you tell which of the other insurances to select if there is no medicaid.  Again this is just ordering.